Remix development tools throwing import error even though the imported package exists
I am getting the error below when I try to run my Remix application. This error comes from remix dev tools. I checked both file paths specified in the error, and they both exist and should work.
Cannot find package '<project path>\node_modules\.pnpm\remix-development-tools@4.2.2_@remix-run+react@2.11.1_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18_jowj2r5lamytlrfivyqi2kheeq\node_modules\react-diff-viewer-continued\package.json' imported from <project path>\node_modules\.pnpm\remix-development-tools@4.2.2_@remix-run+react@2.11.1_react-dom@18.3.1_react@18.3.1__react@18_jowj2r5lamytlrfivyqi2kheeq\node_modules\remix-development-tools\dist\client.js
Did you mean to import "react-diff-viewer-continued/lib/src/index.js"?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling node_modules and pnpm-lock.yaml. I have set auto-install-peers to true in .npmrc as well as running pnpm config set auto-install-peers true.
This error suddenly occurred after pulling some package updates from the repo. It is only happening on my computer, and all others working on this project are unaffected. I tried reverting to an older version of the project, but I am still running into the same error.
I am using VS Code with pnpm as my primary package manager. I am on Windows as well.

npm version: 10.7.0
pnpm version: 9.6.0


My issues was too long paths.
Fixed by adding folling to the .npmrc file
virtual-store-dir-max-length=80

